# Extract the hash value substring from each line in a TextBox

Tags: c#

I am trying to make an app that will verify multiple file hashes at once. The way I've done it is like this: Hash source files from location 1 and output to a textbox filename, hash type and the hash itself.
Hash source files from location 2 and output to another text box the second filename, hash type and hash.

The problem is that that the paths are different, and there are several hashes to verify. I don't know how to split the string to make this work so that just the hashes get checked against the other hashes, without filesnames.

This is how I am getting the hash string:

```
string[] files = filePicketTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

if (files.Length > 0)
{
     foreach (var file in files).. //do hash
```

Here is how the output of the hash gets done:

```
output = file + " MD5 Hash = " + sb.ToString() + "\n";
```

Here's what it looks like in the output textbox:

```
C:\Users\jj\Downloads\hasher.zip MD5 Hash = 8B0A222D30CA4962AFE30511695C8BB3
C:\Users\jj\Downloads\OfficeSetup.exe MD5 Hash = 2E210D07A9AE9B93FAEB0852A0DAFF83
```

And here's what I'm using to verify the hashes:

```
private void VerifyHashes(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string output_one = outputTextBox.Text;
    string output_two = output2TextBox.Text;
    if (output_one == output_two)
    { 
        Verification.Text = "HASHES VERIFIED";
    }
    else
    {
         Verification.Text = "NO MATCH";
    }
```

Can anyone help me with how to split this to remove those filenames and take into account that multiple filenames will be getting verified at once?

Full code:

```
        private void filePickerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the CommonOpenFIleDialog object
        CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
        dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
        dialog.IsFolderPicker = false;
        dialog.Multiselect = true;

        // Check to see if we have a result 
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            filePicketTextBox.Text = string.Join("\n", dialog.FileNames);
        }
        else
        {
            outputTextBox.Text = "Operation cancelled." + "\n";
        }
    }
    private async void runButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.Delete(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "log.txt"));
        // Detect and handle the event of a void filename
        if (filePicketTextBox.Text == "")
        {
            outputTextBox.Text = "No file selected." + "\n";
            return;
        }

        string[] files = filePicketTextBox.Text.Split('\n');

        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Detect and handle the event of a non-valid filename
                try
                {
                    var stream = File.OpenRead(file);
                    stream.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                    outputTextBox.Text = "Invalid filename." + "\n";
                    return;
                }

                // Detect event of no options selected
                if (!(bool)md5CheckBox.IsChecked && !(bool)sha1CheckBox.IsChecked && !(bool)sha256CheckBox.IsChecked && !(bool)sha512CheckBox.IsChecked)
                {
                    outputTextBox.Text = "No hash algorithm selected.";
                }

                // MD5 Calculation and Display
                if ((bool)md5CheckBox.IsChecked)
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        var result = checkMD5(file).Result;
                        WriteIntoTxtBox(result);
                    });
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    progressbar.Value = 0;
                }
```

MD5 Calc code:

```
   public async Task<string> checkMD5(string file)
    {
        string output;

        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            AddValueLoadingBar(20, true);
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                AddValueLoadingBar(60, true);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length);
                int toAdd = 30 / hash.Length;
                foreach (byte b in hash)
                {

                    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
                    AddValueLoadingBar(toAdd);
                }
                output = file + " MD5 Hash = " + sb.ToString() + "\n";
                AddValueLoadingBar(100, true);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: You are creating the `file + " MD5 Hash = " + sb.ToString() + "\n"` string and then you're asking how to split it? The answer is to not create the string in the first place.

Comment: Your workflow seems weird. You have a method that computes the two hashes and then you have another method (that is some sort of event handler) that verifies the hashes. That's like splitting one task into two. Why do you do that? Can you show us the complete code so that we can get better context?

Comment: Sure but it is a bit long. The reason I am splitting it in the first place is that I need to know what files are getting what hashes, and then I can export that info to document the hashes. But for the verification part, I just want to know if the hashes are the same after the files get copied.

Comment: I thought about maybe having two outputs going to two different textboxes, one that has the full file name, one that has only the hash. And then using the second box to verify, but that seems like a very long approach

Comment: You probably want to re-think your approach. You want a class that does your copying or whatever, verifies the hashes, per each file. This can/should be done independent of your GUI. You can then display a user-friendly sentence in each text box. But don't try to reverse your data outputs from a text box content

Comment: "The reason I am splitting it in the first place is that I need to know what files are getting what hashes" - no, you're splitting it because you joined it in the first place. Don't join it, then you don't need to split it.

Comment: @user15919119 - Don't use text boxes to store data. That's what variables, fields and properties are for. Text boxes should be for input or output, not intermediate calculations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you mean this line? output = file + " MD5 Hash = " + sb.ToString() + "\n";

Comment: @user15919119 - Learning to separate processing code from UI code is a good skill to learn.

Comment: @user15919119 - Yes, do not do `file + " MD5 Hash = " + sb.ToString() + "\n"`.

Comment: I am new at this as I'm sure you can tell, sorry

Comment: @user15919119 - Please show us your full code so that we can offer practical suggestions.

Comment: @user15919119 - Don't be sorry, we're here to help, but you need to help us to help you by showing us the full code.

Comment: store a list of objects in memory with the file name and the hash

Comment: Added code to main question

Comment: @user15919119 - I would be able to give you a more detailed answer, that directly addresses some of the other issues you raise, if you provided **all of the code**. If I had more I could give you more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done quite a bit of work to reduce your code down to the bare essentials of computing your hashes **without relying on the UI**. I've then got the code that requires the UI separated out so that it **has nothing to do with computing hashes**.

To start with I created a single hashing function that you can use to compute any hash.

```
public Task<string> ComputeHash(string file, Func<HashAlgorithm> create)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var crypto = create())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                return String.Concat(
                    crypto.ComputeHash(stream).Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've now created two fields to store the list of files and the resulting hashes.

```
private string[] _fileNames = null;
private string[] _hashes = null;
```

I'll show the code that sets the `_fileNames` array later, but for now this is the code that you can call to compute your hashes:

```
private async Task<String> Run(bool md5, bool sha1, bool sha256, bool sha512)
{
    File.Delete(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "log.txt"));

    Func<HashAlgorithm> hashAlgorithm = null;
    if (md5) hashAlgorithm = () => MD5.Create();
    else if (sha1) hashAlgorithm = () => SHA1.Create();
    else if (sha256) hashAlgorithm = () => SHA256.Create();
    else if (sha512) hashAlgorithm = () => SHA512.Create();

    if (hashAlgorithm == null)
    {
        return "No hash algorithm selected.";
    }
    else if (_fileNames == null || _fileNames.Length == 0)
    {
        return "No file selected." + "\n";
    }
    else if (_fileNames.Any(f => !File.Exists(f)))
    {
        return "Invalid filename." + "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        var tasks = _fileNames.Select(f => ComputeHash(f, hashAlgorithm)).ToArray();
        _hashes = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

The hardest part of this code, in my opinion, is the use of `Func<HashAlgorithm> hashAlgorithm` to store the hashing algorithm. If you're not familiar with a `Func<>` then it's worth looking up, but think of it as a way to store a function in a variable so that you can call the function later.

Now, finally, we have the two bits of code that interact with the UI:

```
private void filePickerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
    dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
    dialog.IsFolderPicker = false;
    dialog.Multiselect = true;

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
    {
        _fileNames = dialog.FileNames.ToArray();
        filePicketTextBox.Text = string.Join("\n", dialog.FileNames);
    }
    else
    {
        outputTextBox.Text = "Operation cancelled." + "\n";
    }
}

private async void runButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = await Run(
        md5CheckBox.IsChecked, 
        sha1CheckBox.IsChecked, 
        sha256CheckBox.IsChecked, 
        sha512CheckBox.IsChecked);
        
    outputTextBox.Text = result;
}
```

The end result is that you have two arrays, `_fileNames` & `_hashes` that you can use to get the hash for each file name. No need for splitting text.

Comment: Great job refactoring the code the run multiple hash algorithms. However, the question was not how can I run various hash algorithms, although this is a way to solve that problem although it does provide an alternative method of associating file names with their hashes, which the OP could have capture in his original code in a dictionary without needing to separate arrays.  The code also does not answer the question of how compare an arbitrary set of hashes generated from randomly selected files form two different directories and assure the hashes are the same.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins - The OP doesn't provide any where enough detail on the comparison of the hashes to give any meaningful answer there. How are they getting from an array of 1 or more files to comparing between exactly two different files? I asked for the full code, but they chose only to give part of the code.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins - The most valuable thing I think I could do is show how to separate the UI from the computing of the hashes. Otherwise this question is akin to asking "how can I safely run with scissors?" The only safe and practical answer is to not run with scissors.

Comment: It's cool. Somehow you didn't answer the OPs question, at all,. but were somehow chosen as the correct answer.  The question title is literally "Extract the hash value substring from each line in a TextBox" and the question goes on to ask once you have the hashes how to compare them given different file paths.

Comment: Furthermore, in addition to not even answering the question, you have a single array of file names and a single array of hashes. Now how does one compare and array of  filenames from "some directory" to the file names of an "some other directory" using just an single array? Or compare the hashes for files from TWO different directories using a single array of file names and a single array of directories? Answer you don't. That your answer was chosen as the right answer is highly suspect. You A) didn't answer the original question and B) provide a solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

this works fine:

```
            string[] Files = strFileBuf.Split('\n');
            string[] MyDelim = { " MD5 Hash = " };
            
            foreach (string OneRow in Files)
            {
                string[] TwoParts = OneRow.Split(MyDelim,StringSplitOptions.None);
                string FileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(TwoParts[0]);
                string MyHash = TwoParts[1];
                TextBox1.Text += ("File = " + FileNameOnly + " ->Hash = " + MyHash + "\n");
            }
```

Output:

[image]

So, you can split on the each line (\n)

And then you can assume that the delimiter is the string part inbetween.

So, we split out to file name, and hash.

and then i display ONLY file name (without path) and the hash code.

***EDIT **************************************

Ok, the user wants the output sorted. They should have posted SOME mark up.

Here what we will do:

We assume TWO input strings - the from files, the "to" files.

As noted, I REALLY have to assume that some kind of list or something MUCH better then two strings are the SOURCE of these two file sets.

However, the code that follows could WELL be adapted - and be run directly off the original two "lists" of files.

These two strings - from a text box, from the bottom of the ocean - don't care.

So, we assume this markup on the page:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Height="31px" Text="Button" Width="110px" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
```

A simple button, and a simple gridView.

We will shove/send the results out to the Grid view - sorted.

The code would/could behind the above button could/would look like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strFileBuf1 = "";  ' set this from/input files string

string strFileBuf2 = "";  ' set this to files string

SortedDictionary<string, string> Loc1Files;
SortedDictionary<string, string> Loc2Files;

Loc1Files = GetFiles(strFileBuf1);
Loc2Files = GetFiles(strFileBuf2);

DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();

MyTable.Columns.Add("FromFile", typeof(string));
MyTable.Columns.Add("ToFile", typeof(string));
MyTable.Columns.Add("Match", typeof(string));

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> OneFile in Loc1Files)
{
    DataRow OneRow;
    OneRow = MyTable.Rows.Add;
    OneRow("FromFile") = OneFile.Key;
    if (Loc2Files.ContainsKey(OneFile.Key))
    {
        OneRow("ToFile") = OneFile.Key;
        // compare hash codes
        if (OneFile.Value == Loc2Files[OneFile.Key])
            OneRow("Match") = "Yes";
        else
            OneRow("Match") = "No";
    }
    else
    {
        OneRow("ToFile") = "missing";
        OneRow("Match") = "missing";
    }
}

GridView1.DataSource = MyTable;
GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Output:

[image]

The function/sub that splits out the data and returns that sorted dict list is this - we assume those "two" sets of files as those strings.

```
    public SortedDictionary<string, string> GetFiles(string str)
    {
        string[] Files = str.Split('\n');
        SortedDictionary<string, string> MyList = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (string OneRow in Files)
        {
            string[] MyDelim = { " MD5 Hash = " };
            string[] TwoParts = OneRow.Split(MyDelim,StringSplitOptions.None);
            MyList.Add(Path.GetFileName(TwoParts[0]), TwoParts[1]);
        }

        return MyList;
    }
```

Comment: This would relies on MD5 being the only hashing function. We would also want to sort the file names because they could be in different order.

Comment: Ok, I sort it, assume two sets of files, and I output any miss-match. See the edits part of this post

Answer (score 0):

You *should* format your output with some delimiter other than a space as file names can have space in them, otherwise you will need to account for that.

Your solution is quite awkward and could certainly be reengineered for a better solution.

But to directly answer your question you can join your output into a `Dictionary<string,string>`
where the key would be the file name and value would the hash

```cs
var d1 = outputTextBox.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
    .ToDictionary(
        // use the file name without the directory as the key.
        x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string.Join(" ", x.Take(x.Length - 4))),
        // the has will be the last sequence of characters following the last space
        x => x[x.Length - 1]
    );


var d2 = output2TextBox.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
           .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
           .ToDictionary(
               // use the file name without the directory as the key.
               x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(string.Join(" ", x.Take(x.Length - 4))),
               // the has will be the last sequence of characters following the last space
               x => x[x.Length - 1]
           );
```

After you would need to compare the contents of the two dictionaries using the file names as a key.

This can be done as follows

```cs
///compare the the keys of the two dictionaries match.
var areEqual = d1.Keys
    .OrderBy(x=> x) // sort the first dictionaries keys
    // comare the sorted keys to the sorted keys of the second dictionary
    .SequenceEqual(d2.Keys.OrderBy(x=>x));


if (areEqual)
{
    // if the keys match, then compare the hashes
    areEqual = d1.Select(x => x.Value == d2[x.Key])
        .All(x => x == true);
}
```

Now if you are only concerned with if the files in two directories match, you could just collect the hashes and compare them.

```cs
var outputTextBox = new TextBox();
var output2TextBox = new TextBox();
var hashes_left = outputTextBox.Text
    .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    .Select(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1))
    .OrderBy(x => x);

var hashes_right = output2TextBox.Text
    .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
    .Select(x => x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1))
    .OrderBy(x => x);

var areEqual = hashes_left.SequenceEqual(hashes_right);
```

However, even with these direct answers the proper thing would be to reengineer your code for a more efficient solution, such using a custom class in which you could use to compare strongly typed items in memory.

---

To clarify, reengineering the solution properly using custom classes would look something like this:

```cs
public class FileCollectionComparer
{
    private HashAlgo algo;
    private string[] x;
    private string[] y;

    public FileCollectionComparer(HashAlgo hashAlgo,  string[] x, string[] y)
    {
        this.algo = hashAlgo;
        this.x = x.OrderBy(z=> Path.GetFileName(z)).ToArray();
        this.y = y.OrderBy(z => Path.GetFileName(z)).ToArray();
    }

    public bool AreEqual()
    {     
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;
        else if (!x.Select(z=> Path.GetFileName(z))
                .SequenceEqual(y.Select(z=> Path.GetFileName(z))))
            return false;
        else
        {
            var a = x.GetEnumerator();
            var b = y.GetEnumerator();
            while (a.MoveNext())
            {
                b.MoveNext()
                var xHash = Hasher.GetHash((string)a.Current, algo);
                var yHash = Hasher.GetHash((string)b.Current, algo);
                if (xHash != yHash)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And we might define the `HashAlgo` enum and `Hasher` as:

```cs
public enum HashAlgo
{
    MD5,
    SHA1,
    SHA256,
    SHA512
}
public class Hasher
{
    public static string GetHash(string filePath, HashAlgo algo)
    {
        HashAlgorithm hasher = null;
        switch (algo)
        {
            case HashAlgo.MD5:
                hasher = MD5.Create();
                break;
            case HashAlgo.SHA1:
                hasher = SHA1.Create();
                break;
            case HashAlgo.SHA256:
                hasher = SHA256.Create();
                break;
            case HashAlgo.SHA512:
                hasher = SHA512.Create();
                break;
            default:
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException(nameof(algo), (int)algo, typeof(HashAlgo));
        }
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            return string.Join("", hasher.ComputeHash(fs).Select(x => x.ToString("X2")));


    }
}
```

Comment: _Supposing you where given the data in this format and had no control over changing the source formatting_ - but that’s not the case here, is it?

Comment: Just want to say thanks again for both answers. I've implemented Alexander's quick solution like this. I do plan on reformatting this but I just want to get it working for now`
var areEqual = hashes_left.SequenceEqual(hashes_right);
            
            if (areEqual == true)
            {
                Verification.Text = String.Empty;
                Verification.Text = "HASHES VERIFIED";
            }
            else
            {
                Verification.Text = String.Empty;
                Verification.Text = "HASHES DO NOT MATCH";
             }`

Comment: For some reason it always gives me a hashes verified result, even if the files themselves are different, not regardless of the hashes

Comment: doing it like this `             if (hashes_right == hashes_left)
            {
                Verification.Text = String.Empty;
                Verification.Text = "HASHES VERIFIED";
            }
            else
            {
                Verification.Text = String.Empty;
                Verification.Text = "HASHES DO NOT MATCH";
             }
        } ` always gives a do not match result even if the file and hashes are the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was as simple as adding this line in the hash method.

```
 file = Path.GetFileName(file);
```

Here it is inside the method.

```
       public async Task<string> checkMD5(string file)
    {
        string output;

        using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            AddValueLoadingBar(20, true);
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                AddValueLoadingBar(60, true);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hash.Length);
                int toAdd = 30 / hash.Length;
                foreach (byte b in hash)
                {

                    sb.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
                    AddValueLoadingBar(toAdd);
                }
                file = Path.GetFileName(file);
                output = file + " MD5 Hash = " + sb.ToString() + "\n";
                AddValueLoadingBar(100, true);
            }
        }
        return output;
```

I added this right before the output, causing the output to not include the full path name which is the only thing that changes between the textboxes assuming the hashes are the same. The file name is the same, and if the hash is too, then it's verified.

This caused a lot of work but the answer was quite simple. My code definitely needs some re-writing though :) thanks everyone who answered this.

Comment: Do keep in mind that you've now created a hack to make this work. When you start writing larger and larger amount of code you'll find that the code will collapse under its own weight. Learning how to separate your code will pay off in spades.